# Getting text of all elements within a menu in testcafe

Tags: html, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eobHm.png)I want to get the text of all links within a menu and compare them to the expected texts. I am new to testcafe.

const all_GeneralDisplayTopLink = Selector('nav.shTop').find('ul').find('li');

async areGeneralDisplayedLinksPresent(){

```
let gettexts =  all_GeneralDisplayTopLink;
  var Count   = await gettexts.count;
  console.log(Count + " I need help");// this return four as expected
   for (var i = 0; i < Count; i++){
    var printText = await gettexts.nth(i).textContent;// this throwing an error.
      printText++;
      console.log(printText + " I need help2");
```

Comment: Check the following test example, which is based on your code:``import { Selector } from 'testcafe';
fixture `New Fixture`.page `https://8h6vt.csb.app/`;
test(`New Test`,async t =>{
    const all_GeneralDisplayTopLink = Selector('ul').find('li');
    let gettexts = all_GeneralDisplayTopLink;
    var Count = await gettexts.count;
    for(var i = 0;i< Count; i++){
        var printText = await gettexts.nth(i).textContent;
        await t.expect(printText).eql("Item "+(i + 1));
    }
});``
It works correctly on my side. Can you change it so that I will be able to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try starting the for loop at 1 instead of 0: `for (var i = 1; i <= Count; i++)`

Comment: According to TestCafe documentation, the `index` parameter of the [`nth`](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/selectors/functional-style-selectors.html#nth) method is zero-based.

Comment: @AleksandrProkhorov Ah yes, you're correct. I confused `nth` with the `nth-child` css selector

Comment: I have tried it but am still getting an error, here are the screenshot of the code and the error.

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution:
let gettexts =all_GeneralDisplayLinks;

```
  var Count = await gettexts.count;

   console.log(Count);
    for(var i=0; i<= Count-1; i++){
      var printText = await gettexts.nth(i).innerText;
      console.log(printText + "please help");
      var formated= gatValues.generalDisplayLinks;// get the values from data file.
      var getFomatedValue= formated.split(",");
     await t.expect(printText).eql(getFomatedValue[i]).wait(1000);
       console.log(printText);
    }
```